# Want to change Datein mass (Excel)

Tags: excel, date

I was wondering if someone could help me with this frustrating issue. I want to change my date in mass for example:

I have 30 dates from 1 - 30 (1/10/2017) `dd-mm-yyyy`, so that date I copy all 30 dates and paste it on the next line , so now I have another 30 dates of the same month and year, I want to mass change the month only, so from `1/10/2017` to `1/11/2017`.

Is this possible without doing each one individual?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are in A1:A30.  In A31 put:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,DAY(A1))
```

And copy down.

Though this will cause a problem starting in February and from there on.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below

```
=A1+DAY(EOMONTH(A1,0))
```